# Sinon stub out module's function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, node-mongodb-native

Imagine I have a file here:

```js
// a.js
const dbConnection = require('./db-connection.js')

module.exports = function (...args) {
   return async function (req, res, next) {
      // somethin' somethin' ...
      const dbClient = dbConnection.db
      const docs = await dbClient.collection('test').find()
 
      if (!docs) {
         return next(Boom.forbidden())
      }
   }
}
```

, the `db-connection.js` looks like this:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const dbName = 'test'
const url = process.env.MONGO_URL

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0 // dont buffer querys when not connected
})

const init = () => {
  return client.connect().then(() => {
    logger.info(`mongdb db:${dbName} connected`)

    const db = client.db(dbName)
  })
}

/**
 * @type {Connection}
 */
module.exports = {
  init,
  client,
  get db () {
    return client.db(dbName)
  }
}
```

and I have a test to stub out `find()` method to return at least true (in order to test out if the `a.js`'s return value is true. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit test strategy is to stub the DB connection, we don't need to connect the real mongo DB server. So that we can run test cases in an environment isolated from the external environment.

You can use [stub.get(getterFn)](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v8.1.1/stubs/) replaces a new getter for `dbConnection.db` getter.

Since the MongoDB client initialization happens when you require the `db-connection` module. You should provide a correct URL for `MongoClient` from the environment variable before requiring `a` and `db-connection` modules. Otherwise, the MongoDB nodejs driver will throw an invalid url error.

E.g.

`a.js`:

```js
const dbConnection = require('./db-connection.js');

module.exports = function () {
  const dbClient = dbConnection.db;
  const docs = dbClient.collection('test').find();

  if (!docs) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

`db-connection.js`:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dbName = 'test';
const url = process.env.MONGO_URL;

const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const init = () => {
  return client.connect().then(() => {
    console.info(`mongdb db:${dbName} connected`);
    const db = client.db(dbName);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  init,
  client,
  get db() {
    return client.db(dbName);
  },
};
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('a', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should find some docs', () => {
    process.env.MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
    const a = require('./a');
    const dbConnection = require('./db-connection.js');

    const dbStub = {
      collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      find: sinon.stub(),
    };
    sinon.stub(dbConnection, 'db').get(() => dbStub);
    const actual = a();
    sinon.assert.match(actual, true);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(dbStub.collection, 'test');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(dbStub.find);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  a
    ✓ should find some docs (776ms)


  1 passing (779ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |      75 |       50 |      25 |      75 |                   
 a.js             |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 7                 
 db-connection.js |      60 |      100 |       0 |      60 | 11-13,21          
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: I have added my `db-connection.js` file. Based on your answer, I don't think I can register the `db` object again. Plus, that `find` and `collection` method came from the module's function.

Comment: @felixbmmm Updated answer.

Comment: Great explanation! But what if the return type is a function? I will update my question since I took a different approach to fix my internal issue.

Comment: @felixbmmm If you have a new question, please ask a new one

Comment: I have posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749783/sinon-stub-out-modules-function-from-a-middleware . Thank you for your answer!